# How to calculate general formula for this recurrence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

The recurrences are
$$F_n = a F_{n - 1} + b G_{n - 2}$$
$$G_n = cG_{n - 1} + d F_{n - 2}$$
$$H_n = e F_{n} + f G_n$$
where $a, b, c, d, e, f$ are constants.

How do I calculate $H_n$ in terms of only constants?

Comment: Initial conditions??

Comment: Assume F[0],F[1],G[0],G[1] to be any fixed values.

Comment: In other words, $$\begin{bmatrix}F_{n}\\F_{n-1}\\G_{n}\\G_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & 0 & b \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & d & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_{n-1}\\F_{n-2}\\G_{n-1}\\G_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$ so you can run the recurrence quickly by taking powers of the matrix e.g. using exponentiation-by-squaring. For a more closed solution, see if the constants allow you to diagonalize the matrix (so its powers are easier to compute).

Comment: use Z-Transform of sequences and get a linear equation system in z-domain which can be solved easily.

Answer (score 1):

the z-transform of a sequence is defined like this:
$$ \mathcal Z\{ x[n]\}=X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n} $$
then using this property of Z-transform you get(you can see all information needed for deep introduction to z-transform in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform ) :
$$\mathcal Z\{ x[n]\}=X(z) \Rightarrow \mathcal Z\{ x[n-k]\}=z^{-k}X(z)$$
then your system of equations change's into this:
$$F_n = a F_{n - 1} + b G_{n - 2}\Rightarrow F(z)(1-az^{-1})=G(z)(bz^{-2})$$
$$G_n = cG_{n - 1} + d F_{n - 2}\Rightarrow G(z)(1-cz^{-1})=F(z)(dz^{-2})$$
$$H_n = e F_{n} + f G_n\Rightarrow H(z)=eF(z)+fG(z)$$